# Can't use a combination of fold, count and filter

Tags: scala

I want to count the total amount of `Class2` where `Class2.b == 444`. In this case, there are 4 of them.

```
object Main extends App {
  class Class1(val a: Int)
  class Class2(val b: Int)

  val source = Seq[(Class1, Seq[Class2])](
    (new Class1(1), Seq(new Class2(12), new Class2(2), new Class2(3), new Class2(4))),
    (new Class1(2), Seq(new Class2(222), new Class2(22), new Class2(33), new Class2(444))),
    (new Class1(3), Seq(new Class2(33), new Class2(444), new Class2(3), new Class2(14))),
    (new Class1(4), Seq(new Class2(44), new Class2(444), new Class2(43), new Class2(444)))
  )

  // acc and item are Any!
  val res = source fold(0) { (acc, item) => acc + item._2.count(_.b == 444) }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First error: you can't use point-free notation here:

```
val res = source.fold(0){ (acc, item) => acc + item._2.count(_.b == 444) }
<console>:10: error: value _2 is not a member of Any
       val res = source.fold(0){ (acc, item) => acc + item._2.count(_.b == 444) }
                                                           ^
```

Second error: `fold` method accepts supertype of elements type as the first parameter:

```
def fold[A1 >: A](z: A1)(op: (A1, A1) ⇒ A1): A1
```

In this case it's `Any` (common supertype of `(Class1, Seq[Class2])` and `Int`).

You have to use `foldLeft`:

```
val res = source.foldLeft(0){ (acc, item) => acc + item._2.count(_.b == 444) }
//res: Int = 4
```

To use `fold` you have to convert elements of `source` to `Int`:

```
val res = source.map{ _._2.count(_.b == 444) }.fold(0){_ + _}
// res: Int = 4
```

Note that you could use `sum` instead of `fold(0){_ + _}`, you could also use `view` to avoid intermediate collection creation:

```
val res = source.view.map{ _._2.count(_.b == 444) }.sum
// res: Int = 4
```

### Fold

Method `fold` is not the same as `foldLeft`. It's a special case of method `aggregate`:

```
scala> (1 to 4).par.fold(0){ (a, e) => println(a -> e); 0 }
(0,1)
(0,4)
(0,3)
(0,2)
(0,0)
(0,0)
(0,0)
```

`fold` for parallel collection splits collection into parts (`Seq(1)`, `Seq(2)`, `Seq(3)`, `Seq(4)`), aggregates each part using operation `{(a, e) => println(a -> e); 0}`: `(0,1)`, `(0,2)`, `(0,3)`, `(0,4)` and then aggregates results using the same operation: `(0,0)` 3 times.

In general (method `aggregate`) you have to provide different methods to aggregate each part and to combine results from different parts like this:

```
source.aggregate(0)( (acc, item) => acc + item._2.count(_.b == 444), _ + _ )
// Int = 4
```

Comment: I thought fold was a synonym for fold since foldLeft is more commonly used. If the source code it seemed to be true.

Comment: @Alex: from `fold` documentation: `The order in which operations are performed on elements is unspecified and may be nondeterministic. `. See also `aggregate` method as more general case of `fold`.